# How to add new Code Generation Item for EF Designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, itemtemplate, entity-framework-designer

Can anyone tell me how to create an Item Template that can be used by the EF designer for the Add Code Generation Item option?  I have created the Item Template and it works like a dream!  However, I can't figure out how to get it to show up in the Add Code Generation Item dialog.  FWIW I'm using a VSIX Project to deploy the Item Template.

Answer (score 2):

The .vstemplate file in your Item Template project must have the ADONETArtifactGenerator_ prefix.